# Forcing load submodule of npm package with webpack+ES6

Tags: node.js, import, ecmascript-6, webpack, package.json

I have a npm package with two enviroments. Browser and Server. Is there a way to force webpack loading only a subobject of the package?
This is my index.js:

```
module.exports = {
    browser: require('./browser.js'),
    server: require('./server.js')
};
```

When I try this on the browser:
`import { browser } from 'synko';` webpack is loading server too.

Is possible to have two environments in one npm package? Or I should use browserify?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/defunctzombie/4339901#gistcomment-1582456

So in my case my package.json now have this:

```
"main": "./server.js",
"browser": "./browser.js",
```

And then I can import it like this:
`import synko from 'synko';` for the browser.